# order by condition Django

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I have 3 models userprofile and group :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique =True)
    professionalNetwork = models.ForeignKey('SubForum',null=True, blank=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    professionalNetwork = models.ForeignKey('SubForum')

class SubForum(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How do I get all the groups ordered by first the one that have the same professional network as a specific user then the rest ?

I was looking into something like Group.objects.all().order_by('-professionalNetwork = profile.professionalNetwork') but this doesn't work of course ^^

Thanks you

Comment: Don't you mean filtering?

Comment: filtering will only get me the ones that have the same professional network. I want them all ordered by the one that have the same professional network first.

Comment: This is too localised requirement really. Django supports ordering by values of one or more fields. What you want will need custom condition checking and then ordering. You can either order after you fetch the querysets or write raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (similar to an example in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)). The idea is that you introduce another field which computes whether the group belongs to the specified professional network and then the queryset is sorted by that field.

```
subforum_id = 1  # some id here by which you need to sort

sql = ''.join((
    'CASE professionalNetwork ',
    'WHEN {} THEN 1 '.format(subforum_id),
    'ELSE -1',
))
q = Group.objects.extra(select={'same_subforum': sql})
q = q.extra(order_by=['same_subforum'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
groupRecommendation = Group.objects.extra(
select={
    'network': """
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM axiom_alto_userprofile
    WHERE \"professionalNetwork_id\"= axiom_alto_group.\"professionalNetwork_id\" AND axiom_alto_userprofile.id = %d """ % profile.id, 
},
).order_by('-network')
```

This give me back 1 for group that have the same professional network and 0 for the one who don't ^^